# Nuxt App [Vue warn]:Component inside <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a project with Nuxt 3 and I keep getting this warning in the console

```js
[Vue warn]: Component inside <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated. 
  at <Default > 
  at <AsyncComponentWrapper > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="layout" mode="out-in" > 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <App key=1 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

I dont have a transition yet but i think it's coming from nuxt spinner.

`layouts/default.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <TheHeader />
  <slot />
</template>
```

I checked all my pages and components, all of them have only one root element of the following (`header`, `nav`, `div`, `form`, `NuxtLink`, `button`, `img`)

The warning doesn't specify where it's coming from and I don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nuxt 3 everything should only have 1 root element:

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <TheHeader />
      <slot />
   </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Just read the docs if you stuck on something: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts

Comment: Thank you I knew that but didnt actually noticed it as I thought the problem was in the components or pages.

Comment: @bill.gates — I would really step away from saying "everything", since the documentation sentence literally begins with... "Unlike other components." 

There are many cases where our team does not desire, nor use single-root components. Components, not involved with any transitions, can have multiple roots. No need to wrap in unnecessary extra tags.

Answer (score -1):

If the transition isn’t in your code, I’d simply ignore the warning. As the warning states it will only cause non working animations for that specific component. I wouldn’t spent any time on debugging this since your code will be unaffected.

Edit:
If you really want to debug this, the easiest way is to use the Vue dev tools to search for the transition.

Comment: I'm a begginer but I think that you must NOT ignore any warnings. It may lead to major problems later that will be harder to solve than the first warning, and you'll learn something new as I did with this problem and be more confident in your coding. The transition was coming from nuxt as I said and vue devtools wont help much I think but thanks for helping out.

Comment: No worries, downvoting is fine as it‘s not a real solution as you mentioned. I respect your view and it‘s a great way to deal with problems. However you will come to a point in life where it’s a waste of time to look into issues out of your scope.. for learning it’s for sure a good thing! 

Cheers!